# More examples of Prism (Composite Application Library) Applications?

Tags: prism, cag

The examples that Microsoft's Patterns and Practices provides are quite helpful:

- about a half-dozen simpler **QuickStarts** which touch on specific issues
- the StockTrader **reference implementation**, which is a fairly rounded application

but it lacks a more useful base **application that reads and writes to a data source** (XML or database), allowing users to **login, edit data, logout**, etc. (something like what ASP.NET MVC comes with).

Since Prism applications can get quite complex and lengthy (the StockTrader example is almost 300 files without tests), it would be helpful to have an application that **takes care of the CRUD bulk** that everyone needs to build for most apps anyway.

Does anyone know of any **data-editing Prism example apps** out there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here (http://petedoesstuff.net/Blog/?p=79) you'll find a bunch of links to the samples of using the Prism.

Particularly, LateNight (http://code.google.com/p/cwpfsamples/) may be what you need. It has login screen and data editing functions.

Answer (score 1):

Its feedback I've seen a lot of. I'll pass this onto the Team and see if we can get some more examples put online around this space.

I'm currently writing my own demo app now, so i'll also try and put that online via my blog.

**Scott Barnes - Rich Platforms Product Manager - Microsoft.**

Answer (score 0):

The reason data access was left out of the Prism RI is because it is largely irrelevant to Prism. I would think you're better off looking at something like [DinnerNow](http://www.dinnernow.net/) for those kind of things.

Comment: That link's broken. Looks like it's on Codeplex though: http://dinnernow.codeplex.com/